# when trying to run server in RoR tutorial Hartl 2.2 get this issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I have been following along Hartl's RoR tutorial and am developing the toy_app, however when I try to open the server to move on to 2.2.1 "user tour", I get this error message.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
  :~/workspace/toy_app (master) $ rails server -b $IP -p $PORT
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.0.rc2 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:8080
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2014-12-09 16:29:49] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2014-12-09 16:29:49] INFO  ruby 2.1.4 (2014-10-27) [x86_64-linux]
Exiting
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/2.1.0/socket.rb:206:in `bind': Address already in use - bind(2) for 0.0.0.0:8080 (Errno::EADDRINUSE)
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/2.1.0/socket.rb:206:in `listen'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/2.1.0/socket.rb:461:in `block in tcp_server_sockets'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/2.1.0/socket.rb:232:in `each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/2.1.0/socket.rb:232:in `foreach'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/2.1.0/socket.rb:459:in `tcp_server_sockets'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/utils.rb:75:in `create_listeners'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:132:in `listen'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:113:in `initialize'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:45:in `initialize'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/rack-1.6.0.beta2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:32:in `new'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/rack-1.6.0.beta2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:32:in `run'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/rack-1.6.0.beta2/lib/rack/server.rb:286:in `start'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/railties-4.2.0.rc2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in `start'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/railties-4.2.0.rc2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/railties-4.2.0.rc2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/railties-4.2.0.rc2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/railties-4.2.0.rc2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/railties-4.2.0.rc2/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/toy_app/bin/rails:8:in `require'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/toy_app/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:27:in `load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:27:in `call'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client.rb:26:in `run'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/spring-1.1.3/bin/spring:48:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/toy_app/bin/spring:16:in `require'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/toy_app/bin/spring:16:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:3:in `load'
        from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 2):

A well asked question often already contains an answer:

```
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/2.1.0/socket.rb:206:in `bind':
Address already in use - bind(2) for 0.0.0.0:8080 (Errno::EADDRINUSE)
```

Something appears to be already running on port 8080 of your local machine. You can't have two on same adresses and ports at once. You'll either need to terminate what that is, or pick a different port.

Answer (score 0):

You can't run two servers on the same port. Just try different port or kill server which works on port 8080.

command:

```
rails server
```

starts server on port 3000

to use different port, you need to specify port using option `-p`.
In your case, you used port 8080, because your `$PORT = 8080`